# Including jsp fragments within a jsp page in Struts

Tags: jsp

I am writing a Struts2 application.

I want to create a `header.jspf` fragment that calls an action but will also be including in other jsp pages using . On inclusion, the main jsp pages are showing the `<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>` in the header.jspf as normal text.

A main jsp is below:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>`enter code here`
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title><s:property value="title"/></title>
<s:include  value="/WEB-INF/content/jspf/homeheader.jspf" />
</head>
<body>
<div>
<div>
<s:action name="allcategories" var="cat" ></s:action>
<s:iterator value="#cat.categories">
<s:property  value="name"/>
</s:iterator>
<s:a action="showcatreg" >input category</s:a>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the header.jspf

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<div id="header">
<h1>BOOKSELLER</h1>
<div>
<ul>
<li><a><img src="" alt="home"/></a></li>
<li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
<li><a href="">Help</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li><a href="">Wishlist</a></li>
<li><a href="<s:url action="showadmin"/>">click here</a> </li>
</ul>
</div>
<img src="" alt="bookseller logo"/>
<p><input type="search" value="Search Items"/></p>
<h2>Welcome to the home of books online</h2>
<ul>
<li>Sign in</li>
<li>New Here? Register</li>
<li>Contact Us</li>
</ul>


</div>
```

the result in screenshot:

[image]

Comment: @RomanC Not a dup of linked question.

Comment: If you want to use fragments then don't include them with S2 tags. Or just don't use fragments.

Comment: @AleksandrM Which question then?